# How to allow back-order even if the stock status is 0 in Opencart platform?

Tags: opencart

How to allow customers to select the size even if the stock is mentioned Zero in Opencart platform? If for example I have a tshirt in 5 different sizes but have only two sizes currently in stock but I would like to allow customers to back-order sizes which are not currently available in stock.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I am new to stack overflow and not sure how to go about things, but the concern I raised is genuine....

Answer (score 0):

You will need to edit the file **catalog/controller/product/product.php** somewhere around line 350 (will vary depending on version) look for the line which reads:

```
if (!$option_value['subtract'] || ($option_value['quantity'] > 0)) {
```

and change it to:

```
if (!$option_value['subtract']) {
```

The second part which I removed tells the controller to omit options with a value less than 1.  A side effect of this is that you will end up with option quantities in the negative - but this may be desirable if you want to keep track of how many are back-ordered.